# Programmatically comparing two MP4 (mpeg-4) videos

Tags: python, video-processing, mp4, video-encoding

I'm working on software that will create MP4 videos using the [MLT Framework](http://www.mltframework.org/twiki/bin/view/MLT/WebHome).  I need to create some unit tests for my processes that will compare a pre-testing creating video with the one that is created.  I am using Python for the code.  I need to ensure that the content of the videos is the same.  What are the ways that I can programmatically compare the two videos?

Comment: Both files will be byte by byte equal?

Comment: By "the content of the videos is the same", do you mean "visually about the same", "bit-for-bit identical MPEG streams", or something in between? Keep in mind that the output of an MP4 encoder may not be entirely deterministic.

Comment: That's also part of the issue, I'm not sure what the best way to compare them is.  I need to make sure that if I create a video that is made up from a 2 clips with a fade transition between the two it will come out the same each time given the same inputs.  Since I am doing this for unit testing, I need to do it programatically.  So it's probably in between the two choices from @duskwuff.

Answer (score 4):

One common metric for comparing video files is [SSIM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SSIM) (structural similarity) -- videos with a high SSIM are likely to be "equal".

There are a number of tools available for calculating the SSIM of two video files; one such tool is available at: https://github.com/kahkeng/vqats